# Migrate Struts-Tiles to Spring + tiles 3

Tags: java, spring-mvc, migration, struts-1, apache-tiles

I'm migrating to SpringMVC and Apache Tiles 3 from a Strut1 + Tiles project. I know only a little about Struts1+Tiles, it is too old and I'm stuck in Controller and ComponentContext in Struts-tiles. According to document from apache website, it was replaced by ViewPreparer and AttributeContext but I dont know the following line means: 
`ComponentContext compContext=(ComponentContext)pageContext.getAttribute(ComponentConstants.COMPONENT_CONTEXT,PageContext.REQUEST_SCOPE);`
 
What is `ComponentConstants.COMPONENT_CONTEXT`? and how to change `ComponentContext` to `AttributeContext`

Please Help, Thanks.

Comment: I think you'll struggle to find people that can you help you with Tiles from Struts-1 days. There's this documentation regarding re-using the tiles-1 configuration http://tiles.apache.org/2.1/framework/migration/configuration.html but here you're wanting to move past that to tiles-3 where such configuration style was removed. Maybe if you post a larger example i might be about to help you, i can at least explain what AttributeContext does, but i can't promise anything.

Comment: Thanks for your consideration, i am maintaining a very big project, it is hard to explain here. In my opinion, the ComponentContext stores the values what we put in tiles definition and we can get it in Java code by the above code line. In tiles 3, the ComponentContext has been no longer used and replaced by AttributeContext. But I dont know how to get it in Javacode like ComponentContext. Pls help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bidi, there are 2 ways of getting an AttributeContext:

The first one, like mck stated: through "org.apache.tiles.AttributeContext.STACK" key of request scope. However, the value is a STACK that contains 2 elements of AttributeContext type. The one we need is the first element. IMHO, this way is limited because since the data structure is a stack, getting also mean removing from the stack according to FIFO rule, so you can use the object for only once.

I am using the second way in my project. Because the execute() method of ViewPreparer already have a parameter of AttributeContext type, and this method is always called each time a page is rendered, so you can use this object to do the thing you want (or put it in request) when overriding the method. 
AttributeContext is just a collection of key/value pairs. Normally, people use it to get access to some values which are attributes in the template, so fetching the values and putting them to the request can save the overhead. You can also create some static properties of the inheriting class and setting the values to them.

Answer (score 0):

With the Spring-4 and Tiles-3 integration set up (there's spring docs on this as well as a number of good tutorials around) then the properties you put into spring's model map will be available in your jsps, this is not related to the AttributeContext.

AttributeContext only the other hand is (basically) only for holding the map of attributes.  Attributes here are defined within a definition, used to identify template or string attributes (as is typically declared in you xml definitions), and come with properties of role, renderer, expression, and/or value.

If AttributeContext is what you are after: you can get hold of it through the current tilesContainer, and to get hold of the current container use the static TilesAccess, eg

```
TilesContainer tileContainer = TilesAccess.getCurrentContainer(request);
AttributeContext attributeContext = tilesContainer.getAttributeContext(request);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the code here is in a custom tag code. It is used to execute a complex logical method. I exactly need to get the AttributeContext but the "request" parameter here is not a HttpServletRequest, it is an org.apache.tiles.request.Request. What I can get is only the PageContext from jsp api as well as its HttpServletRequest. Can you give me the "number of good tutorials around" ?

Comment: beyond that, to get a grasp of the more advanced side of things, i would take a read of http://tech.finn.no/2012/07/25/the-ultimate-view-tiles-3/  (the site just got migrated so excuse the code formatting, we're working on that).

Comment: You need access to your ApplicationContext. With that you can also call TilesAccess.getContainer(context), or create your own Tiles Request from ServletRequest.  Or you can look inside your request scope and find your "TilesContainer" under the TilesAccess.CURRENT_CONTAINER_ATTRIBUTE_NAME key

Comment: So, the ApplicationContext of tiles and ApplicationContext of spring are diferent, right ? How to get it ? Sorry for my lack of knowledge about that problem but the docs from apache isn't good

Comment: ApplicationContext from Tiles (yes they both have their own version).

Any improvement to the docs would be greatly appreciated, there's no better author than s/he with the fresh perspective.

Comment: "… Or you can look inside your request scope and find your "TilesContainer" under the TilesAccess.CURRENT_CONTAINER_ATTRIBUTE_NAME key"

i think this is the easy approach for you now.

Comment: Yes, I know it and I have already get the ApplicationContext of Tile, but there is no method of it to get the Tiles Request. Is there any relationship btw Request of Tile and HttpServletRequest ?

Comment: Right. But with the applicationContext though you can also get the TilesContainer with `TilesAccess.getContainer(appContext);`

Comment: Thank for all your comments. You r the only one who helps me this problem until now. Ok, let's sum up all again. I need to get the AttributeContext. Now I have already got the ApplicationContext of Tile and TileContainer. But the method getAttributeContext need a Tile Request as a parameter, and what I have now are the above things and HttpServletRequest. How do I get the Tile Request from them ?

Comment: Yes you are right. You can create a Tiles' Request from the appContext+request+response you've got (it doesn't need to be the same instance).
You can also take a look in the request scope for something under the "org.apache.tiles.AttributeContext.STACK" key (although again this is kinda a hack taking advantage of how tiles stores its variables).

Answer (score 0):

Bidi,
 take a read of http://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/advanced/runtime.html

particular the "Runtime Composition using APIs" section.

```
TilesContainer container = TilesAccess
        .getContainer(request.getSession().getServletContext());

Request tilesRequest = new ServletRequest(
        container.getApplicationContext(), 
        request, 
        response);
```

otherwise i suggest you take a dive into the Tiles codebase, it's not complicated code, especially the TilesAccess, Request, ApplicationContext stuff.

Comment: Thank you in advance, let me try it.